# requesting api with authentication keys using AFHttpClient

Tags: ios, rest, authentication, afnetworking

I am trying to use AFHTTPClient to make a rest api call. I am trying to make the api request by passing the Authentication key I got from registering to the api. When I run the app, I get 403 error. I am new to using AFNetworking and I would really appreciate any help on this.

```
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://somewebsite.com/"]];

[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization: Client-ID" value:@"xxxxxxxx"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                        path:@"https://api.somewebsite.com/api/category/subcategory/fun/"
                                                  parameters:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Print the response body in text
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing with AFHTTPClient is that you set the base url in the init method.. then every requestWithMethod call.. you pass in a relative URL from the base... for example,

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"https://api.somewebsite.com/"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                        path:@"/api/category/subcategory/fun/"
                                                  parameters:nil];
```

Comment: That is exactly is wrong with my code. That is really helpful. Thank you so much for saving me headache :)